# Reset variables in services in angular once the user is logged out

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

So, the project architecture is : Angular + Firebase. Angular component calls the service’s methods to save/retrieve data from Firebase.

Behavior : A user logs-in, does some activity (saves/retrieves data) and logs out. Another user logs-in in same/different tab but same browser window, he saves some data. 
**The data is saved in the previously logged in user’s location in Firebase.**

So, I want to confirm is this an expected behavior?

In service’s constructor, I have written a code to fetch the currently logged

```
constructor() {
    this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    // some other code
}
```

But that’s never called out for the second/consecutive user of the application (after the first/previous user has logged out).

I’m not sure, but want to confirm, isn’t the service’s constructor be called out once again when a new user logs-in? 
Or let me put this way, once the user has logged out, the “user” variable of the “service” shouldn’t be set to null because firebase.auth().currentUser return null if there is no currently logged-in user !

Answer (score 0):

A service is a **singleton**, meaning there's only one and only one instance of them during your application lifecycle.

So no, it won't be called twice. This is your issue.

What you could do to solve that is make a function that makes what your constructor do, and call this function on your user login. This way, your user data will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> A user logs-in, does some activity (saves/retrieves data) and logs
>   out.

?
are you not doing this on logout?

```
  signOut() {
    this.user = null;
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }
```

If so there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, I have used firebase.auth().signOut(); in Auth service , but not in UserDetails service.

Comment: should be at one place and call for everyother services/components.

Comment: Yeah, I’ll take care of it. Thanks for suggestion!